# Use callKit to show call history in UI iOS

Tags: ios, callkit

I am trying to use the CallKit in my VoIP App to show the call history in UI iOS.
But I can not find any tutorial to how use CallKit and write code in VoIP App.

Comment: there is no API's exposed to read the call logs .

Comment: I believe it exist with iOS 10, infact when you make call from Skype or Whats App you can see in your call history the call that you did from whats App or Skype.

Comment: Hope this fulfil your needs ..https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to make a VoIP app which uses CallKit I recommend starting by reviewing Apple's sample code app, [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html), which demonstrates using CallKit.

**There is no API for an app to query or read from the device's Recents list** (aka call history records). *But if an app uses CallKit, its calls will be included in the Recents list.*

Comment: No need to ask request authorization, when creating provider delegate.